# Eclipse g++ not found in path: windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, windows-7, g++

I am attempting to setup SDL2 for C++ with Eclipse on Windows 7.

In order to do so, I am following the tutorial in [this link](http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-eclipse-windows/), which states that I must first install MinGW. So I follow the [link](http://zamma.co.uk/installing-mingw-windows/) provided in order to setup MinGW. I follow all the steps without issue. I then open Eclipse and attempt to build a simple hello world program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, this code doesn't build, with 6 errors.

I then proceed to simplify the program further:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This also does not compile. There are two errors:

1. Program "g++" not found in PATH
2. Program "gcc" not found in PATH

Here is a screenshot.
[image: build errors]

However, my path does contain "C:\mingw\bin". I have also tried changing this to "C:\mingw". Looking inside "C:\mingw\bin", I find gcc and g++:[image: gcc and g++ in mingw\bin]

In addition, compiling a test program using the command line (g++ Test.cpp -o Test) works just fine, as does "g++ -v".

I have been searching the web for hours, and can't seem to find an answer as to why Eclipse can't seem to compile anything with MinGW. Questions I have looked at on SO (which haven't been able to fix my issue) include:

1. [Eclipse mingw binary not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686064/eclipse-mingw-binary-not-found)
2. [Eclipse not finding c std libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948320/eclipse-not-finding-std-c-libraries)
3. [g++ not found in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477725/program-g-not-found-in-path)
4. [Eclipse C++ : "Program g++ not found in PATH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703432/eclipse-c-program-g-not-found-in-path)
5. [Program g++ not found in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609482/program-g-not-found-in-path)
6. [Program g++ not found in path C++ [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323334/program-g-not-found-in-path-c)
7. [Eclipse CDT (Juno) in Win7: Cannot find g++ in PATH, iostream unresolved and other fun stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565614/eclipse-cdt-juno-in-win7-cannot-find-g-in-path-iostream-unresolved-and-oth)

**Additional info:**
Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Settings > "CDT GCC Built-in Complier Settings MinGW [Shared]" : *Toolchain MinGW GCC is not detected on this system*.

I have also reinstalled Eclipse to no avail.

I realize that this may be a duplicate question of some that I have linked, but the information in previous questions have not been able to fix my problem, and I fear that adding a comment to an old question may not result in an answer.

*Please request additional information as needed.*

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the environment for the c/c++ builder.

- First you need to install the GNU tool-chain, you can choose either MinGW or Cygwin. You can see the steps [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_c_before_you_begin.htm&cp=9_0). I used MinGW.
- Go to **Window->Preferences->C/C++->Build->Environment** and add a new variable, name it whatever you want for example a named it "MINGW", now paste the binaries directory of MinGW which is by default **C:\MinGW\bin**, you should have something like this:

[image]

- Now when you create a new project you just have to select the MinGW tool-chain:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though I have fixed the problem for the moment.

In case others encounter the same issue:
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Command changed from "g++" to "C:\mingw\bin\g++".